# querying many-to-many-relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a many-to-many relationship with models Competition and Season with a pivot table named competition_season.

Season->belongsToMany->Competitions->hasMany->Teams->hasMany->Players

I want to query the data of all players in a team in a specific season.

something like

```
\App\Player::with('team.competition.season')->where('team.competition.season.id', 2);
```

However since season is a collection (competition has many seasons) at this moment i can never query it like this.

Can someone point me in the right direction to properly select all players in a team in a particular season?

Comment: I believe you should add `->get()` to the end

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add relation hasManyTrough at your model (read more about at: [has-many-through](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through))
Then, all you need is "whereHas"

```
$players = \App\Player::with('season')->whereHas('season', function($q){
     $q->where('season.id', '=', 2);
})->get();
```